# curl command not reading the file properly

Tags: bash, curl, azure-pipelines

I am performing curl like below from the Azure pipeline.

```
kubectl exec ${podName} -- curl -w "@test.txt" -vik --resolve ${{ parameters.DomainPrimary }}:443:$IPPrimary ${APP_ENDPOINT}
```

my test.txt contains data like

```
            time_namelookup:  %{time_namelookup}\n
            time_connect:  %{time_connect}\n
            time_appconnect:  %{time_appconnect}\n
            time_pretransfer:  %{time_pretransfer}\n
            time_redirect:  %{time_redirect}\n
            time_starttransfer:  %{time_starttransfer}\n
                    ----------\n
            time_total:  %{time_total}\n
```

```
Warning: Failed to read test.txt*
```

I wanted to print all the time related info for the curl call. Any inputs could be helpful

Locally from my ubuntu shell curl call works fine as with response it will print the time info

Comment: is test.txt present (baked) in the pod?

Comment: @RakeshGupta No, I will check that by copying the text file to POD.

Answer (score 1):

use kubectl command to get the file lists or directory in your pod.

```
  kubectl exec  [your pod name]  -- ls
```

Check the result. If it does not exist, use cp command to copy files to a pod.

```
  kubectl cp test.txt  mypod:/path/
```

Test in my pod with bash, it works.

[image: result]

Comment: How is the issue going? If it helps, you could accept the answer, this will help other users who has the same issue.